# Enable or Disable Form Validation based on the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am actually doing this in CakePHP 2.x.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('url' => array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'add'), 'id' => 'form-add')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input("title", array("div" => false, "label" => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required'=>true)); ?>

<?php  echo ($this->Form->input('description', array('type' => 'textarea', 'rows' => '6','div'=>false, 'label'=>false, 'placeholder'=>__('Description...'), "class" => "form-control Description", 'required'=>true)));?>

<button class="btn" type="submit" id="submitSaveDraft">Save Draft</button>

<button class="btn" type="submit" id="submitSave">Save</button>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

I have a form with some fields and two submit buttons. One submit button is "Save Draft", and the other is just the standard "Save".

1) If the "Save" button is clicked, the page will validate all inputs on the form, i.e. if there are required fields which are not filled, a message will be prompted and the form will not submit.

2) Now, what I want to achieve is this: When the "Save Draft" button is clicked, I want the page to ignore all the required fields (other than the Title field), and proceed with the form submission. This is because we are only saving a draft, so all fields but the Title are not required.

How can I achieve number (2), saving draft functionality above?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to give them different names, then check the name in your controller data.

Comment: Are the required fields only required by the html inputs or do you have any validation Rules in your model which require these fields?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest limiting the default validation on the Product model to only title. This will allow the draft form to submit without the auto-added HTML5 validation getting in the way. The rest of the validation can be set to a different Product model class var that will be used later, something like `$save_validation`.

Next, send the submit type (e.g. Save or Save Draft) to the controller, likely with a hidden input that's changed on button click, with a JS form submit handler.

In your controller code that handles the posted data, you can check which case you're in, and for the `submitSave` case, set the model's `$validate` array by merging `$validate` and `$save_validation` (prior to save of course). Now you have your full set of validation, and it's only applied when needed.

Answer (score 0):

to bypass validation.

```
$this->model->save($data, ['validate' => false]));
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the type submit for the "save draft button"